# Python requests no Exception on status 400

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm setting up a small Python script so my colleagues can collect data from a certain internal API based on a few inputs using the following code:

```
url = "https://....."
params = dict(...)
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
client.prepare_request_body(scope=[])
session = OAuth2Session(client=client)
response = session.get(url=url, params=params, verify=session.verify)
```

where the params are based on the manual inputs. I can guarantee some of the inputs will not conform to the API's requirements fully (like lower case letters where upper case is needed, etc.). In this case, the API will return a response with status 400:

```
>> response
<Response [400]>
>> response.text
{"statusCode":400,"errorMessage":"Bad Request","errors": ...}
>> response.status_code
400
```

I thought I could capture this with `response.raise_for_status()`, but no Exception is raised, and the returned value is `None`:

```
>> response.raise_for_status()
None
```

Why is this? I thought the raise_for_status function was supposed to raise an Exception based on the response's status_code

Comment: raise_for_status() on a response from the *requests* module **will** raise an HTTPError exception if the HTTP status code is 400. I can only imagine that this peculiarity is related to OAuth2Session

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472298/how-to-capture-api-failure-while-using-oauthlib-oauth2-fetch-token) may help

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes! Setting ```session.register_compliance_hook("access_token_response", "raise_on_error")``` indeed gives me a ```HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request```, though I think I want it to hook on protected_request instead (I'll dig into this more). Any idea if it's possible to customize the Exception? I'd like to add the error message from the response into the Exception

Comment: @DarkKnight Nevermind, figured it out already :). Could you post your comment as answer, so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raise_for_status() on a response from the requests module **will** raise an HTTPError exception if the HTTP status code is 400. This is a peculiarity of OAuth2Session which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472298/how-to-capture-api-failure-while-using-oauthlib-oauth2-fetch-token)